# What are the transaction fees with Ripple.com?

Tags: ripple

https://ripple.com/how-ripple-works/

> While Ripple does not charge a typical fee for profit, each
>   transaction does require a small portion of a ripple (equivalent to
>   ~1/1000th of a cent) for security.

This seems to assume a certain conversion rate between Ripples (XRP) and real world money. How much in XRP is the TX fee?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default fee for a transaction is 0.00001 XRP.

But the fee is not fixed. Quoting [the wiki](https://ripple.com/wiki/Transaction_Fee):

> Transaction fees are adjusted based on two factors: base fee and load
>   fee
>
> **base fee: long term fee adjustments**
>   Since transaction fees are
>   paid in XRP and the price of XRP may change overtime, to keep the
>   price of transactions affordable, Ripple uses an adjustable "base fee"
>   to specify the cost of transactions.
>
> **load fee: short term fee adjustments**
>   The "load fee" can rise quickly to protect the network
>   from attacks and keep the network functional under heavy load.

The fee schedule is changed using consensus, [quoting. D.Schwartz](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=142150.msg1517807#msg1517807):

> A node can introduce a transaction to change the base fee. If a
>   trust-weighted majority of nodes vote "yes" on the transaction, it
>   will be incorporated into the ledger and the fee will be changed.

Comment: Long term adjustments: `When we want to change the base fee or multiplier, we just release a new version of the software with a new base fee (or publish a new fee schedule). People can tweak that, but they probably won't. People might not upgrade, but they probably will`

Comment: @ripper234 they are talking about software "server-side", I hope.